# Getting error each time building the project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Whenever I open or rebuild my project the warning and sometimes the error comes:

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018.
```

It is showing the warning in build.gradle which has this code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.espoir.myappid"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can anyone help me resolve this please? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update Project level `build.gradle` libraries to the latest version.

**Update**

Upgrade you both class path to the latest versions

Like This:

`YourProjectName/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io"}
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: @PrateekAggarwal you might as well accept the answer as it has solved the problem :)